# How to fix reducing the width of the left div element when increasing the size of the right div's child elements?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, flexbox

I arranged the following UI as left, right panels using `flex box`.
the right panel element's child elements are arranged vertically using `white-space: nowrap;` css property.

when I increasing the right panel child elements ("comps") widths, the left panel width is reduced instead of showing a vertical scroll bar in the right panel.
how can I fix this?

(added two buttons for increase the child element width ans reset)
[image]
[code pen snippet](https://codepen.io/azadnio/pen/VwPqrVZ)

```js
$(function(){

      $('#inc-width').click(function(){

        $('#inner-div').width($('#inner-div').width() * 2);
      });

      $('#reset-width').click(function () {

        $('#inner-div').width(1000);
      })
    })
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  width: 20em;
  height: 40em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button id="inc-width">Increase child element width</button>
    <button id="reset-width">RESET child element width</button>
  </div>

<div class="parent">

    <div class="left">
      LEFT PANAL
    </div>

    <div class="right">

      <div style="flex: 1;">
        <div class="inner-wrap">
          <div class="inner" id="inner-div"></div>
          <!-- <div class="inner"></div>
          <div class="inner"></div> -->
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Why should anything show scrollbars, when you are not setting `overflow` anywhere?

Comment: @CBroe the overflow property set to `.inner-wrap` element (wraper element of child elements).

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex-basis with a specific width and you can do other container flex-basis auto.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

Comment: can you modify the codepen snippet as your answer/